Rate of failure of broadcasting is getting increased
Rate of failure of broadcasting transaction is getting increased in few days.
Is there any options to solve this problem?
I set my priority fee price as 6M. CU is enough for the transaction.
When network gets busier, more transactions are getting failed. I've got the txid but can't find it anymore. Should I create a retry logic to prevent this kind of failure? or is there another options for this?

Correct, if you're adding in a priority fee for your transaction, but it's still not landing, it's likely not even making it to the leader to be included in a block. In that case, retrying your send is a perfectly valid solution..
You can read all about retrying at https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions/retry
